# Can TypeScript make React component instantiation type safe?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I'm very new to TypeScript and React, so apologies for any incorrect or confusing terminology. Basically this is what I'm looking at:

```
<MyComponent someNumber="40" />
```

`someNumber` is a property defined as `number`, but I'm noticing the following behavior:

- If I pass a non-number value, e.g. `<MyComponent someNumber="foo" />` this still compiles but blows up at runtime
- If I fail to pass any value, e.g. `<MyComponent />` this still compiles even if there's no default value for `someNumber`

Ideally those two scenarios should fail to compile, but I don't see a way to do this. I'm on TypeScript 2.0.6 if it helps.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define an interface for the component props then the compiler will check all of that for you:

```
interface MyProps {
    someNumber: number;
}
interface MyState {}
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {}

let a1 = <MyComponent someNumber={ 40 } />; // fine
let a2 = <MyComponent />; // Error: Property 'someNumber' is missing in type ...
let a3 = <MyComponent someNumber="40" />; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

---

### Edit

The problem had something to do with the react definition files the OP was using.
Installing the definition using:

```
npm install @types/react
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: I am actually doing that now, but I'm referencing `MyComponent` from an external file. Still not getting any errors though.

For reference, this is the example I'm working on:

* Instantiation: https://github.com/rolodato/volca-keys-editor/blob/15a4d58b44856588c27ce5b00af9b5391557f024/src/index.tsx#L26-L29
* Definition: https://github.com/rolodato/volca-keys-editor/blob/15a4d58b44856588c27ce5b00af9b5391557f024/src/parameter.tsx#L3-L14

Comment: I've also tried instantiating an invalid component in the same file that it's defined in, still not getting any errors from the compiler though.

Comment: Using version 2.0.3 I'm getting A LOT of errors trying to compile your code. Things like: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'` and `Property 'initialValue' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Parameter> & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'`. Please update your question with your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Strange, it compiles just fine on my end. Added the tsconfig.json to the question.

Comment: It looks ok. How are you compiling? `tsc` from command line? Inside an IDE?

Comment: I am using VS Code, normally it shows the same compile errors as running `tsc` manually. Neither `tsc` nor VS Code show any errors.

Comment: Try to compile something simple that isn't supposed to, for example: [let a: string = 3;](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20string%20%3D%203%3B)

Comment: Yes, that fails as expected, both on VS Code and when running `tsc` manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126937/discussion-between-nitzan-tomer-and-rodrigo-lopez-dato).